# Based on a "yes/no" question in the form, I want to update one field within the existing collection in Webflow

Tags: jquery, webflow

I've tried contacting Zapier and Webflow on how to do this but they have been unable to help much. Basically, I have a form with only has yes and no answers, depending on the answers, I want to show a div within the collection item saying that the item is unavailable. (This should be multiple items that will be made "unavailable"). The form is located on a different page from the collection pages so I can't use it like a filter. I'm thinking that Jquery should be able to do this?

Initially, I wanted to turn on the "unavailable switch", which is a field in the collection, but I'm okay if there is another workaround. All the other fields in that collection remain the same. I'm a designer with basic knowledge of HTML, CSS and Javascript...